# How to get paypal API credentials?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using Paypal recurring payments and direct payment.

I tested it using beta-sandbox and works fine.
Now I want to make to real paypal account.

I have been given real paypal account, and I login with it on https://www.paypal.com/, but I don't know how can I generate API Credentials ?

this looks completely different from sandbox environment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>Check out this guide to [Obtaining API Credentials](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECAPICredentials) from PayPal. You will find how to create/view/remove your API signature/certificate in PayPal's *live* setting.</s>

Update

As per the comment, the previously held answer is out of date. To obtain your API credentials, [log in here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run).

Comment: This is not helpful. Check out the direct URL in the comment from Rashid on Nov 19 https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run

Comment: Nice to see that URL supplies API credentials regardless of the user's permissions! Another load of rubbish from PayPal...

Answer (score 11):

If you want to retrieve the api user name, api password and api signature for live then you can get it directly by [log in](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) to [this url](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run) from Paypal.

Answer (score 3):

Log in to Paypal. Click Tools or hover over Tools and click All Tools from the drop down menu. Sort alphabetically and API Credentials will be the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Login to PayPal, go to Profile and then Selling tools. Click the update link on API access and request API credentials. Refer to [this link](http://www.paysketch.com/paypal-api-credentials/) for a detailed step by step guide.